# Are there any tools, packages or frameworks for writing unit and/or integration tests with markdown?

Tags: unit-testing, cucumber, markdown, bdd, gherkin

Cucumber BDD framework documentation mentions that they intended isolating it from the Gherkin language so they might possibly, in the future, support another reader-friendly language, namely Markdown. Gherkin is a well thought-out BDD language but the implementation of unit tests as separately created, separately managed, regular-expression-driven step definitions has me polarized. Have there been any successful attempts at launching a BDD markdown-driven project? I dream of using the code syntax formatting for writing the actual tests with thoughtful, project-dictated utility libraries working behind the scene to configure mocks, assertion libraries and so forth.

Comment: The creator of Markdown has explicitly stated that he is completely opposed to Markdown having a specification written. The [rules](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) are the closest you would get, but I suggest reading the [Babelmark 2 FAQ](http://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/faq.html) for some a nice summary of issues with that some people have with that.

Comment: Some of those people went on to create [CommonMark](http://commonmark.org/), which is similar to Markdown, but has a fully fleshed out spec with many examples and complete tests. Personally, I prefer the plan old Markdown, but you will be hard pressed to find unit tests that aren't tied to a specific implementation (and the specific behavior of that implementation). Although, there was a (now abandoned) effort in [markdown-testsuite](https://github.com/karlcow/markdown-testsuite) which may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @Waylan ! The spec I'm dreaming of would be a fork/branch/spirit-of Markdown that builds on top of it by interpreting code blocks and keywords in headers/table-cells/bolds/underlines  to run a suite of tests. It would be a replacement for Gherkin and Cucumber by not forcing the separation of test code and feature specs.

Comment: Checkout [Gauge](http://getgauge.io) if you intend to do any functional testing, which uses simple markdown to write your specs and supports multiple languages.

Comment: Thanks @apoorvam! That appears to be what I'm looking for; will start looking more into it ASAP. Post it up if you want some cred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout [Gauge](http://getgauge.io) if you intend to do any functional testing, which uses simple markdown to write your specs and supports multiple languages. It's open source too!

It has a modular architecture with support for plugins, and has parallel execution which is as simple as adding a flag during execution. It also has good IDE support, Integration with CI/CD tools, build tools etc. Find more [here](http://getgauge.io/documentation/user/current/).

Answer (score 1):

DaSpec creates tests from specifications in Markdown. It was written by BDD expert Gojko Adzic. I haven't used it and it does not seem to have been maintained.

- [DaSpec Hello World example](https://github.com/daspec/www.daspec.com/blob/master/guides/hello_world.md)
- [Announcement](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/announcing-daspec-10-awesome-executable-markdown-gojko-adzic/)

Gauge is probably going to meet your requirements, as per apoorvam's answer.